# How do I make one hyperlink which shows its target page as a modal dialog when clicked?

Tags: developer

There are lots of links in CiviCRM which will: (a) open an overlaid modal dialog when clicked, and (b) open the same content in a new page when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicked or middle-clicked. This is cool and I want to make one link which does this.

I see [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0f03f337533bb76fb7fe6dcc25cdd624daef24f3/CRM/Custom/Page/Field.php#L46) that *pages* can enable this behavior for *all links within the page* by extending `CRM_Core_Page` and setting `public $useLivePageJS = FALSE;`. Neat, but not quite what I want.

I'm building an extension where I want to achieve the same result, but for one link which would live at the top level of the CiviCRM menu. Is there a class I can add somewhere, or a javascript function I can call somehow that will enable this "modal" functionality for one link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple actually. Add the css class `crm-popup` to the link and you're done :)

Comment: That's pretty great!!